# Charindex returns false position in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, line-breaks, charindex

I'm trying to get the charindex for multiple CHAR(10) characters in a string in SQL Server.

The first and second linebreaks are found alright, the 3rd one is a problem however.

```
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres) AS '1st linebreak',
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres,(CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres)+1)) AS '2rd linebreak',
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres,(CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres)+1)+(CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres))) AS '3rd linebreak',
```

In the example below, the second entry is okay. The first entry results in a false value for the 3rd linebreak (the || represent the CHAR(10) in my datasource).

I'm assuming the character on the right is causing this, but I can't find out how (and why).

```
Entry nr1:  Line 1||Line 2||Line 3||Line 4||
Entry nr2:  Line 1||Line 2||Line 3||Line4
```

I tried to trim the trailing CHAR(10) on the first line, this did not do anything however.

Comment: Please include proper sample data and your full working query

Comment: Keep in mind that in Windows, linebreaks are CR+LF, ie Carriage Return + Line Feed, ie char(13)+char(10). Check your string out in an editor.

Comment: Thanks, will check this in the future. This time, it only contained CHAR(10).

Answer (score 1):

If 2016+, consider the following JSON approach

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([subaddrs] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
 ')
,('Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line4')
 
Select Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
      ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
      ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
      ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
      ,Pos5 = nullif(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]'),'')  -- nullif() optional
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(
                           string_escape(
                           replace(
                           replace([subaddrs],char(13),'')
                           ,char(10),'||')
                           ,'json')
                           ,'||','","'
                           )+'"]'
                      ) ) C(JS)
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. After checking the query again (and again), it looks like the nested Charindex was faulty.

The query below does the job:

```
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres)-1 AS '1st linebreak',
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres,(CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres)+1)) AS '2nd linebreak',
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres,(CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),subadres)+1))+1) AS '3rd linebreak',
```